# Magento 2: Magento Brute Force Attack

Tags: magento2.3

After all findings, Not able to understand how to resolve this issue.

```
We were unable to perform one or more Brute Force checks.
This may expose your installation to Brute Force attacks.Error occurred while checking URL(s):
/catalog/Adminhtml_category
/catalog/AdminHtml_category
/catalog/AdminHtml_CategorY
/cms/Adminhtml_block
/cms/Adminhtml_block/index
/cms/Adminhtml_Block/Index
/cms/Adminhtml_block/edit
/cms/Adminhtml_bloCk/ediT
/cms/Adminhtml_page
/cms/Adminhtml_pAge
/customer/Adminhtml_inDex
Check that access to this URL(s) is restricted at the web server configuration level.
```

I am getting this issue in site scanning.

```
Magento ver: 2.3.0
```

Anyone have any idea

Thanks!